# Gcc 4.8.2 default compiles and runs variable length arrays fine

Tags: c, gcc, variable-length-array

In C programming I came across a situation where I accidentally initialized an array with variable size and it worked. I did a bit of research and apparently variable length arrays are available from C99 compilation. Apparently, GCC 4.8.2's default compile option is C98.

Here is the code I used to test:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h" // rand(), srand()
#include "time.h"

void printArray(const char* c) {
    // impossible to get size of c because it returns pointer size
    int array[sizeof(c)/sizeof(char)];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<(sizeof(c)/sizeof(char))-1; i++) {
        int fill=-1;
        if(c[i]=='a')
            fill = 0;
        else if(c[i]=='b')
            fill = 1;
        array[i]=fill;
    }
    printf("contents of array in binary: \n");
    for(i=0; i<(sizeof(c)/sizeof(char))-1; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void printRandomArray() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    // variable length array is possible using C99
    int array[rand()%10];
    int i;
    printf("contents of random array: \n");
    for(i=0; i<(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); i++) {
        array[i]=rand()%10;
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char c[]="abbabbabbaababababababb";
    printArray(c);

    printRandomArray();
    return 1;
}
```

printRandomArray() shouldn't work because I compiled using GCC 4.8.2 default which is C98 but it works. Could anybody explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: Bill Lynch your answer was exactly something I was looking for because it explained why things compiled with different specification of C which happened to be supported at default with the GCC 4.8.2 why did you delete?

Comment: @BillLynch try `-std=c89 -pedantic` and `-Werror` or `-Werror=vla`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Ah. There we go. Thanks!

Comment: @user3064869: With BLUEPIXY's idea of adding `-pedantic`, it's back up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So GCC supports two different versions of C89. It supports `c89`, and `gnu89`. The latter means that a number of gcc extensions are enabled.

The default standard language for GCC 4.8.2 is `gnu90`, which is identical to `gnu89`. [<sup>[see gcc documentation]</sup>](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Standards.html)

Let's look at the different warnings / errors we get when we use those different languages:

#### GNU89 and GNU90

```
[2:10pm][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/gcc            asd.c
[2:10pm][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/gcc -std=gnu89 asd.c
[2:10pm][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/gcc -std=gnu90 asd.c
[2:10pm][wlynch@apple /tmp]
```

#### C89

```
[2:10pm][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/gcc -std=c89 asd.c
asd.c:2:21: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
 #include "stdlib.h" // rand(), srand()
                     ^
asd.c: In function ‘printArray’:
asd.c:6:5: error: expected expression before ‘/’ token
     // impossible to get size of c because it returns pointer size
     ^
asd.c:15:9: error: ‘array’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         array[i]=fill;
         ^
asd.c:15:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
asd.c: In function ‘printRandomArray’:
asd.c:26:5: error: expected expression before ‘/’ token
     // variable length array is possible using C99
     ^
asd.c:30:24: error: ‘array’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     for(i=0; i<(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); i++) {
                        ^
[2:10pm][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/gcc -std=gnu89 asd.c
[2:10pm][wlynch@apple /tmp]
```

If we fix those errors, and then also compile with `-pedantic`, we will see the diagnostic that you are looking for:

```
[2:28pm][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/gcc/4.8.2/bin/gcc -std=c89 -pedantic asd.c
asd.c: In function ‘printRandomArray’:
asd.c:27:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘array’ [-Wvla]
     int array[rand()%10];
     ^
asd.c:27:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside C99 standard, GCC also allow variable length array as an extension:

#### [6.19 Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++.

AFAIK, GCC 4.8.2 compiles code in `-std=gnu90` mode by default. Compile it with option `-std=c89` and you will see plenty of warnings and errors.

Comment: Interesting: GCC (4.9.1 tested) accepts both `-std=c89` and `-std=c90` and it means basically the same thing; ditto `-std=gnu89` and `-std=gnu90`.

Comment: I mean only that the options with 89 and 90 are both treated as equivalent and valid.  The code I was messing with had `//` comments in it, not the VLA code above, and I got semi-appropriate warnings (since the code is excruciatingly obscure, testing `#include <./*some*/header.h>` to be precise).

Comment: To be clear, I was not previously testing the code in the question at all.  When I tested the code in the question, the `//` comments were rejected (warned about) with `-std=c89`.  However, the VLA was not rejected until I used `-std=c89 -pedantic` (or `-std=gnu89 -pedantic`).  Even then, it was just a warning until I added `-Werror`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Still surprising to me. If you compile the same code in GCC 4.8.2 with option `-std=c89`, you will get so many warnings and errors.

Comment: I got 1 warning and 4 errors with code from the question compiled in C89 non-pedantic mode, mainly because of the `//` comments. With those replaced by `/* */` comments, the the code compiled cleanly without `-pedantic`, and with one warning about the use of the VLA when compiled with `-pedantic`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Same happened with GCC 4.8.2! I replaced `//` with `/* */` and code compiled fine (without `-Pedantic` flag). o.O

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's no such thing as C98. It is C89/90, then C95 (which is usually merged into C89/90), then C99 and so forth.

Secondly, GCC compiler in its default mode does not implement any standard C at all. The language it is compiling is called GNU C. There's nothing unusual in it supporting VLA by default. You have to manually configure GCC in order to make it conform to any C standard. Switches like `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` are a must.